# Too late to reverse a down vote?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

I got down-voters remorse, as I don't think I was being fair. But now its too late for me to reverse it. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In addition to [@random's answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24544/too-late-to-reverse-a-down-vote/24545#24545), you could also leave a comment asking the author to do a minor edit, so you can undo your vote.

Answer (score 7):

- Bookmark the answer in your browser of choice. (Leave a note to yourself as to why you'll be coming back to the post.)
- Continue using the site until you have at least 2000 juicy rep points.
- Go back to the answer and edit it. This will reset the counter for votes.
- Reverse your downvote to an upvote or just take back the vote.

Or just wait for them to edit their post and undo or reverse your vote then.

Comment: Great, so the whole shortening of the vote lock-in time was pretty much useless to avoid vote fraud as along as you have enough privileges.

Comment: If you edit the question/answer simply to change your vote, everyone can see it. So it's not totally useless.